# How to delete rows from grouped data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

[image]

I want to leave a maximum of two entries per **live_login**, which records sorted by **last_login_ts**.

As a result, you should get:

[image]

**!** If is it possible, than using only SQL, without php and other tools.

**P.S.** Sorry for my english :)

**ANSWER**:

```
delete gr.* from my_table gr inner join (Select x.* from my_table x join my_table y on y.live_login = x.live_login and y.last_login_ts <= x.last_login_ts group by x.live_login, x.last_login_ts having count(*) > 2) gh on gh.live_login=gr.live_login and gh.dead_login=gr.dead_login;
```

Thank you, **Strawberry**!

Comment: does this table also have maybe an id column?

Comment: @pala_ No. This table have only three columns.

Comment: @pala why? It doesn't appear to need one.

Comment: @pala_ This table have PK (live_login, dead_login)

Comment: @Strawberry another train of thought i had. irrelevant now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select x.* 
  from my_table x 
  join my_table y 
    on y.live_login = x.live_login 
   and y.last_login_ts <= x.last_login_ts 
 group by x.live_login
     , x.last_login_ts 
having count(*) <= 2
```

Or something like that

Comment: Sometimes, people don't really know what they want

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Apparently this ANSI/ISO SQL compliant answer doesn't work with MySQL. Can be used with most other dbms products anyway, so I don't delete the answer.

Delete a row if there are two (or more) newer rows with same live_login:

```
delete from tablename t1
where 2 <= (select count(*)
            from tablename t2
            where t2.live_login = t1.live_login
              and t2.last_login_ts > t1.last_login_ts)
```

Comment: This SQL return error: "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't1 where 2 <= (select count(*) from `my_table` t2 where t2.live_login = t1.live_' at line 1"

Comment: three upvotes and it doesn't work - you can't delete from a table that you refer to in the subquery.

Comment: Aside from the fact it doesn't work (apparently), you don't really want to count all do you?

Answer (score 1):

This works, but is ugly, and probably suboptimal:

```
delete logins from logins
inner join (
  select l1.live_login, l1.last_login_ts second, q1.last_login_ts min 
    from logins l1
    left join
      (select live_login, min(last_login_ts) last_login_ts 
        from logins 
        group by live_login) q1
    on q1.last_login_ts < l1.last_login_ts 
      and l1.live_login = q1.live_login
    where not exists 
     (select 1 
       from logins 
       where live_login = q1.live_login 
         and logins.last_login_ts > q1.last_login_ts 
         and logins.last_login_ts < l1.last_login_ts) 
     and q1.last_login_ts is not null) q
on q.live_login = logins.live_login and logins.last_login_ts > q.second;
```

demo fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3145/1

Comment: Thank you, but it's very long query.

Comment: It's not the size of the query that counts. It's how you use it!